# How to capture disk folder structure?

Tags: c#

What would be the shortest way to capture folder structure in code? I would like to have a more or less reusable strictly typed approach to use in scripts instead of stringly typed paths we all usually deal with. Here is how a part of my simple “system info” utility looks like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach(var cursor in SystemDisk.Windows.Cursors.Animated)
        Console.WriteLine(cursor);
}
```

Where:

```
using static System.IO.Directory;

public static class SystemDisk 
{        
    public static string Drive { get; set; } = "C:";
    public static string AutoexecBat => $"{Drive}\\Autoexec.bat";
    public static class Windows
    {
        public static string Path => $"{Drive}\\Windows";
        public static string SystemIni => $"{Path}\\System.ini";
        public static class Cursors
        {
            public static string Path => $"{Windows.Path}\\Cursors";
            public static IReadOnlyList<string> Animated => GetFiles(Path, "*.ani");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you need this folder structure for? Please [edit] the question and add some details about what you want to do with these paths.

Comment: @RolandIllig here it is. It is supposed to be a reusable type though, just a way to get intellisense hints while typing file paths - so i can not know all the use cases.

Comment: @DmitryNogin `folder structure` do you mean files and folders that inside that folder ? like the command prompt line `dir` ?

Comment: @iSR5 yep, something like this. I would like visual studio to get me a hint about what is next while typing in a file path - compiler should check my paths basically. It could work with registry keys as well.

Comment: It sounds like you want a `Trie` structure.

Comment: @tinstaafl Yep, something like this. No dynamically allocated memory though - it makes it be different from data structures. I want it all be visible to C# editor/compiler.

Comment: Did a simple search on google and found [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ionutvmi.path-autocomplete).  Looks like exactly what you want.

Comment: @tinstaafl Thanks, but it works with VSC only (not VS), developer's machine could have different folder structure (different root for a project is a very realistic thing to happen). I also would like to change property types to something like `public static IniFile SystemIni => $"{Path}\\System.ini"` to have a handy manipulation API in-place.

Comment: @DmitryNogin are you trying to use a Visual Studio extension for that ? or are you trying to make a new one ?

Comment: @iSR5 neither of that. Any extension will probably depend on local disk folder structure which will be different on a server, so i am not a big fun of them all. What i need is my own class, a C# type, which is relatively easy to define and very, very easy to use in many places across the app. The class api should mimic folder structure (i need almost the same for capturing a shape of my registry key hierarchy too). The cheapest way to have a hierarchical class api in C# is to use nested static classes as far as i can see.

Comment: @DmitryNogin I'm trying to understand what are looking for, from what I understood so far, you're trying to create a shared class or an internal library which generates a directory path dynamically. so for instance, you type `OSDrive`, this would generate the path of the Windows directory (e.g. `C:\Windows`) as you don't need to have fixed paths, you need the class or library to be working on any server that runs `Windows` is much similar to Windows Environment variables (e.g. `%APPDATA%`) , is that what are you asking for?

Comment: @iSR5 I would like to document in code important files and registry keys of my app in a strictly typed way, so I would like a type with a hierarchical api as registry and disk files/folders are hierarchical by nature. It should drive me when I need to provide a file path, etc.

Comment: @DmitryNogin Oh, so you just want to convert constants into a strong typed objects right ?

Comment: @iSR5 Yep, kind of. Just looking for a "hierarchical" configurable representation which mimics the nature of the target media to reduce recognition gap :)

Comment: @DmitryNogin, now we are in the same page I guess ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the idea you're trying to achieve, however, this would be too much work to do if you're going to implement it this way.

If you are still convinced that this is the only way, you can use `struct` and define the OS structure like you did, and keep it only for path something like this :

```
public struct SystemDisk
{
    private static string Drive => Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory);

    //using Refelction, will give you the object's full name, we then convert it to string and adjust it to be parsed as an OS path.
    private static string GetPath(Type type) => @Drive + @type.FullName.Substring(type.FullName.IndexOf('.') + "SystemDisk".Length + 2).Replace('+', Path.DirectorySeparatorChar) + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;

    public struct Windows
    {
        public static string Root => $@"{GetPath(typeof(Windows))}";

        public static string SystemIni => $@"{Root}System.ini";

        public struct System
        {
            public static string Root => $@"{GetPath(typeof(System))}";
        }

        public struct System32
        {
            public static string Root => $@"{GetPath(typeof(System32))}";
        }

        public struct Cursors
        {
            public static string Root => $@"{GetPath(typeof(Cursors))}";
            public static IReadOnlyList<string> Animated => GetFiles(Root, "*.ani");
        }
    }
}
```

if you're going to continue on this road, and you need to create a `struct` for each directory in the system folders, you can write a method to get the directories, and then design a model for it, then returning this model as string, then just copy and paste. To do that, you'll have to get first the directories, then get each directory name, after that, you'll remove any special chars from the name, then just make a  model template and pass the directory name to it, get the representative string, and copy / paste into the class.

Here is method to camel case the name :

```
public static string CamelCase(string str)
{
    str = str.Replace(".", " ").Replace("-", " ").Replace("_", " "); 

    return str.Contains(" ")
        ? string.Join("", str.Split(' ').Select(x => char.ToUpper(x[0]) + x.Substring(1)))
        : char.ToUpper(str[0]) + str.Substring(1);
}
```

now we can do a method to build the model template :

```
public static string StructModelBuilder(string name, int indentlevel, string body = "")
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);

    string indentLv1 = indentlevel == 0 ? string.Empty : new string(' ', indentlevel);

    string indentLv2 = indentLv1 == string.Empty ? new string(' ', 4) : new string(' ', indentlevel * 2);

    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    sb.Append(indentLv1);
    sb.Append($"public struct {name}");
    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    sb.Append(indentLv1);
    sb.Append("{");
    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    sb.Append(indentLv2);
    sb.Append($"public static string Root => $@\"{{GetPath(typeof({name}))}}\";");
    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);               
    sb.Append(body);           
    sb.Append(indentLv1);
    sb.Append("}");
    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

now, we can create a method where we get the directories list, and just pass them to the template to get the model

```
public static string GetStructureModel(string path)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        return string.Empty;


    //Directory.GetDirectories($@"{path}", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);  // to include all sub-directories (recursively).
    var root_dir = Directory.GetDirectories($@"{path}");// just get the top level directories.

    // remove the last Directory Sparator Charcter (e.g. back-slash \) and get the name of the directory
    var root_name = path.TrimEnd('\\').Substring(path.LastIndexOf(System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar) + 1);

    var rootNameCamelCase = CamelCase(path.TrimEnd('\\'));

    var sb = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);

    var model = StructModelBuilder(rootNameCamelCase, 0, "@body");

    foreach (var dir in root_dir)
    {
        var dir_name = path.TrimEnd('\\').Substring(path.LastIndexOf(System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar) + 1);

        var dirNameCamelCase = CamelCase(dir_name);

        sb.Append(StructModelBuilder(dirNameCamelCase, 4));
    }

    return model.Replace("@body", sb.ToString());           
}
```

now you just pass the path like this :

```
var model = GetStructureModel(@"C:\Windows");
```

you can from here take the model, paste it into the class, and adjust whatever needed. this is not perfect, but it should get the job done.

personally, I wouldn't go this far if I were in your seat, instead, I'll use Window Environment Variables instead, to not re-invent the wheels. also, I'll make use of `Enum` and make things shorter. For instance, instead of making a full path to the `System32`, I'll just use an `Enum` and define `System32`, and with a simple `switch` statement, it'll return the full path, and so on. this would make more sense to me and would be easier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I think I would do it manually, as I just would like to document important relevant file/registry entries only and developer machine file structure could be different. Generally speaking, I was just looking for a cheap way to define hierarchical class API which could be useful in many applications to reduce presentation complexity. It is a shame that in 2020 we have no native language mechanism for that being done syntactically efficient :)

Comment: @DmitryNogin the only issue is that you are trying to search for nails in a farm to put them in one box. It's possible, but it will not be easy. because the actual system paths are spread between .NET classes, each for its uses. you'll find something like `KnownFolders` but this even don't have all the folders. I have not played with Windows SDK, but I'm sure you'll find something useful there. You'll need to get the actual class or object that define the system path you need instead of store it as string, so if there is any updates on the path, your library should catch the new path for it.